# Optimisation pairs from array, sum of the pairs is Random value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried below code for print the pairs from array, the pairs sum is random value. but is there any other way to optimisation in JS?

```
var array = [1,24,10,12,11,13,23,9,15];r 

var value = 24;

function myMthod(array,value){

       var a;
       var b;

    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {

        a = array[i];

        for (var j=0; j < array.length; j++) {

            b = array[j]

            if ( (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)) === value && result.indexOf(a+","+b) == -1 && result.indexOf(b+","+a ) == -1 ) {
               result.push( a+","+b )
            }

        }    
    }

return result

};
myMthod(array,value);
```

Is there any way to provide the optimisation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want exactly to achieve with this code?

Comment: output is ["1,23", "12,12", "11,13", "9,15"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the second loop, when you got an item, just check if there's `value - item` in the array:

```js
function pairs(array, value) {
    var rs = [];

    array.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if (array.includes(value - item, index))
            rs.push([item, value - item]);
    });

    return rs;
}

var array = [1,24,10,12,11,13,23,9,15];
var value = 24;


console.log(pairs(array, value))
```

Comment: `includes` loops too, but nice.

Comment: @georg, awesome sir.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the code working. You need to change the `100` to `value`

```
if ( (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)) === value && result.indexOf(a+","+b) == -1 && result.indexOf(b+","+a ) == -1 ) {
//                                   ^^^^^
```

Better change it to a version without `parseInt`, because you work with numbers.

```
if (a + b === value && result.indexOf(a + "," + b) == -1 && result.indexOf(b + "," + a) == -1) {
//  ^^^^^
```

```js
var array = [1, 24, 10, 12, 11, 13, 23, 9, 15];
var value = 24;

function myMthod(array, value) {
    var a, b, result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        a = array[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            b = array[j];
            if (a + b === value && result.indexOf(a + "," + b) == -1 && result.indexOf(b + "," + a) == -1) {
                result.push(a + "," + b)
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(myMthod(array, value));
```

A slightly faster version could ignore the already looped items and work without a check for inserted items.

```js
var array = [1, 24, 10, 12, 11, 13, 23, 9, 15];
var value = 24;

function myMthod(array, value) {
    var a, b, i, j, result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        a = array[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            b = array[j];
            if (a + b === value) {
                result.push([a, b]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(myMthod(array, value));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @Nina, I Got the solution, can we do it with out using second loop?

Comment: @Coder, no, you need a second loop, either with a recursive approach or directly.

Comment: so we can't do any Optimisation in this code or we can't go any better way ?

Comment: yes, you could sort it and break early in the inner loop.